# Incorrect syntax near ')'. --- SQL

Tags: syntax, subquery, brackets

It's showing error on first group by bracket:

```
select  
    attnDate, workLoc, swipeType, fromTime, toTime, timeInterval,  
    sum (ECount1 + ECount2) as EmpCount, 
    EmpCode 
from
    (select
         attn_dt as attnDate, att.work_loc as workLoc, 
         vEmpDtl.emp_Code as EmpCode,  
         case 
             when convert(time, in_Ts) between '7:00' and '10:30' then 'IN'   
             when convert(time, in_Ts2) between '7:00' and '10:30' then 'IN'  
             else ' ' 
         end as swipeType, 
         count(in_Ts) as ECount1, count(in_Ts2) as ECount2,
         td.from_time as fromTime, td.to_time as toTime, 
         td.time_interval as timeInterval,  
         in_Ts as inTime, out_ts as OutTime  
     from 
         emp_attn att 
     cross join 
         time_details td  
     inner join 
         v_emp_dtls vEmpDtl on att.emp_code = vEmpDtl.emp_code
     join 
         emp_mst mst with (nolock) on mst.emp_code = vEmpDtl.emp_code  
     join 
         (select distinct empRep.emp_code  
          from emp_reporting_structure empRep  
          where empRep.report_to = '18501') o on o.emp_code = vEmpDtl.emp_code 
     where
         attn_dt between '2023-02-01' and '2023-02-28'  
         and vEmpDtl.emp_type = 'COMMON'  
         and vEmpDtl.emp_loc_type = 'KSACORP' 
         and vEmpDtl.work_loc_id = '300000001672100'  
         and vEmpDtl.nationality = 'Sri Lanka'  
         and vEmpDtl.payroll_code = 'KSA Retail Payroll'  
         and vEmpDtl.country_code = '6486' 
         and vEmpDtl.region = 'RIY' 
         and (convert(time, in_Ts) between convert(time, td.from_time) and convert(time, td.to_time) or
              convert(time, in_Ts2) between convert(time, td.from_time) and convert(time, td.to_time))  
         and (convert(time, in_Ts) between '7:00' and '10:30' or  
              convert(time, in_Ts2) between '7:00' and '10:30') 
         and vEmpDtl.emp_code not in (select distinct emp_code  
                                      from exclude_emp 
                                      where exclusion_type = 'NO_ATTENDANCE')
         and mst.contract is null  
         and vEmpDtl.employment_status = 'All'  
          ---  group BY att.attn_dt desc  ,att.emp_code 
        ) AnyNameYouLikeButYouHaveToGiveOne 
     group by 
         attn_dt, att.work_loc, in_Ts, out_ts, in_Ts2, out_ts2,
         from_time, to_time, time_interval, vEmpDtl.emp_Code) aaa 
group by 
    attnDate, timeInterval, workLoc, swipeType, fromTime, toTime, 
    ECount1, ECount2, EmpCode
```

Please suggest code changes for this query

Answer (score 1):

The query has an error in the first GROUP BY clause. There are extra commas after swipeType and before FROM. Please remove those commas, and the query should run without errors.

```
SELECT attnDate, workLoc, swipeType, fromTime, toTime, timeInterval, SUM(ECount1+ECount2) AS EmpCount, EmpCode 
FROM (
    SELECT attn_dt AS attnDate, att.work_loc AS workLoc, vEmpDtl.emp_Code AS EmpCode,
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(time, in_Ts) BETWEEN '7:00' AND '10:30' THEN 'IN' 
             WHEN CONVERT(time, in_Ts2) BETWEEN '7:00' AND '10:30' THEN 'IN' 
             ELSE ' ' 
        END AS swipeType, 
        COUNT(in_Ts) AS ECount1, 
        COUNT(in_Ts2) AS ECount2, 
        td.from_time AS fromTime, 
        td.to_time AS toTime, 
        td.time_interval AS timeInterval, 
        in_Ts AS inTime, 
        out_ts AS OutTime
    FROM emp_attn att 
    CROSS JOIN time_details td 
    INNER JOIN v_emp_dtls vEmpDtl ON att.emp_code = vEmpDtl.emp_code 
    JOIN emp_mst mst WITH (NOLOCK) ON mst.emp_code = vEmpDtl.emp_code 
    JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT empRep.emp_code 
        FROM emp_reporting_structure empRep 
        WHERE empRep.report_to = '18501'
    ) o ON o.emp_code = vEmpDtl.emp_code 
    WHERE attn_dt BETWEEN '2023-02-01' AND '2023-02-28'
        AND vEmpDtl.emp_type = 'COMMON' 
        AND vEmpDtl.emp_loc_type = 'KSACORP' 
        AND vEmpDtl.work_loc_id = '300000001672100' 
        AND vEmpDtl.nationality = 'Sri Lanka' 
        AND vEmpDtl.payroll_code = 'KSA Retail Payroll' 
        AND vEmpDtl.country_code = '6486' 
        AND vEmpDtl.region = 'RIY' 
        AND (
            CONVERT(time, in_Ts) BETWEEN CONVERT(time, td.from_time) AND CONVERT(time, td.to_time) 
            OR CONVERT(time, in_Ts2) BETWEEN CONVERT(time, td.from_time) AND CONVERT(time, td.to_time)
        ) 
        AND (
            CONVERT(time, in_Ts) BETWEEN '7:00' AND '10:30' 
            OR CONVERT(time, in_Ts2) BETWEEN '7:00' AND '10:30'
        ) 
        AND vEmpDtl.emp_code NOT IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT emp_code 
            FROM exclude_emp 
            WHERE exclusion_type ='NO_ATTENDANCE'
        ) 
        AND mst.contract IS NULL 
        AND vEmpDtl.employment_status = 'All'
    GROUP BY attn_dt, att.work_loc, in_Ts, out_ts, in_Ts2, out_ts2, td.from_time, td.to_time, td.time_interval, vEmpDtl.emp_Code 
) aaa 
GROUP BY attnDate, timeInterval, workLoc, swipeType, fromTime, toTime, EmpCode, ECount1, ECount2
```